# Limit of $z^2$ as $z \to i$

Tags: complex-analysis

> I am trying to prove $$\lim_{z \rightarrow i} z^2=-1.$$

---

From the definition, given $\epsilon > 0$, I need to determine $\delta > 0$ such that $0< |z-i| <\delta$ implies $|z+i|<\epsilon$. I rewrite
$$|z^2+1|=|z-i||z+i|<\delta|z+i|$$
How could I prove $$\delta|z+i|<\epsilon$$?

Comment: You want to look at $|z^2+1| = |z+i|\cdot|z-i|$.

Comment: @ mfr Yes, I assuming δ is smaller than 1 but how could I find the boundary of |z+i|?

Comment: $|z+i| = |z-i + 2i| \le |z-i|+2$ (for example)

Comment: Hint: If $|z-i|<1$ then $|z+i|<3$ hence $|z^2+1|\leqslant3|z-i|$. Can you end this?

Comment: So, for any δ, it is smaller max(ϵ/3,1)

Comment: What you want to prove is that for any $\epsilon$ there exists $\delta$ such that $|z-i| < \delta$ implies $|z^2+1|< \epsilon$. And you have to rewrite $|z^2+1|=|z-i||z+i|$, not $|z^2+i|$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all observe that $|z^2+1|=|z-i||z+i|$

Now suppose that $|z-i|<1$. Then $|z+i|=|z-i+2i|\leq |z-i|+|2i|$<$3$

That is when $|z-i|<1$ , $|z+i|<3$.

Proof:
Let $\epsilon>0$ be arbitrary.

Choose $\delta=min{(1,\frac{\epsilon}{3})}$

Now suppose that $|z-i|<\delta$.

Then observe that $|z^2+1|=|z-i||z+i|<3|z-i|\Rightarrow |z^2+1|<\epsilon$.

Therefore $\lim_{z\rightarrow i}z^2=-1$